# How does Google's "password reset" page make a div tag into a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a script to automate form submission, but this page has me stymied.

My script can find and fill in the inputs, but there's no submit button, only a div block with text in it. There isn't even an  tag in the div block, nor can I find any urls in the css code for the page, so none of the ways I've learned to turn a div tag into a link apply.

Just to be clear, the page is

```
https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/password?[more, apparently random but probably personal, information]
```

Comment: (using Chrome) Try right-clicking the div in question and selecting "Inspect". Once done, look to the panel in the bottom-right of the screen with tabs labeled "Styles", "Computed", "Event Listeners", "DOM Breakpoints", "Properties". Select the 3rd one - "Event Listeners" - there should be a handler for the click event. :)

Comment: You can use the `onclick` attribute to create clickable divs. Example: https://css-tricks.com/creating-clickable-divs/

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a clickable div in a general sense, or how your script that automates form submission could deal with other pages that already have such controls?

Comment: enhzflep: Thank you, but when I looked at the Event Listeners, there was nothing there (the panel was blank).

Sam: Thank you, but that wasn't the case with these <div> elements.

@nnnnnn I'm asking specifically how Google implemented a clickable div in this case, with the goal of finding out how my script can deal with it (and pages like it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, just a little CSS and Javascript or jQuery and yes, one way or another Google is using CSS and Javascript to make a `<div>` look and feel like a link `<a>`.

```js
//regular, good old javascript, no jQuery
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.getElementById('clickableDiv').onclick = divClicked; //assign a function to to action on onclick events for the div element with id = clickableDiv
});


function divClicked() {
    var url = this.getAttribute("data-href"); //this is the element in the DOM clicked
    alert('I have been clicked and I will go to page: ' + url + ' if you uncomment the next line of code');
    //window.location.href = url;
}

/*
jQuery example
$(function(){
  $('#clickableDiv').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).data('href');
    alert('I have been clicked and I will go to page: ' + url + ' if you uncomment the next line of code');
    //window.location.href = url;
  });
});*/
```

```css
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickableDiv" class="clickable" data-href="myurl" tabindex="1">Click Me</di>
```

Comment: You can simulate a click using the jquery function click
`$('#clickableDiv').click();`

Comment: Note that if you make a div act like an anchor you should also give it a tab-index so that keyboard-only users can get to it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, because I found the "cursor: pointer;" line in a surrounding div. But where (or how) can I find the JQuery?

Comment: Google might not be using jQuery, the are probably using "vanilla" Javascript infant

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see the Javascript way, no jQuery needed

Comment: You will notice two things, the CSS and HTML stay exactly the same.

Comment: @Miryafa trying to use F12 developer tools to inspect Google pages and web applications can be very challenging, Google use advanced levels of web software engineering and development to make anything they do, they delivered, minified and obscured javascript making it hard to read or find actual code that is doing the work you in a feature that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    (<button type="button" onclick="validator goes here">Click here</button>)
```

It is a button and replace validator goes here with the answer above.

Comment: So you're saying that you can make a div behave as a link by using a `<button>` element?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that's what's happening here, because I can't find any <button > tags.